# In Windows is there a way can you go back and find out application wanted to make changes after it was denied?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, logging, uac

In Windows (7), an application wants to make changes and you deny permission.

Is there a way can you go back and find out what it was that wanted to make changes?

Comment: Is there anything in the event logs?

Answer (score 0):

Look for event 4673 in the Security log.  Program is listed in the details as ProcessName.